# ElementaryOS crashes while watching YouTube videos

Tags: crash

I switched recently to elementaryOS. It just works fine but it crashes while watching YouTube videos. Sound starts repeating and machine become unresponsive. Or sound goes on but machine is unresponsive. In either case I have to restart. This happens almost everyday. Any recommendations?

---

I'm trying to read the crash dump. So far no luck! Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40912668/593308)

I found offset with

```
sudo od -t x1 -A d /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-77-generic | grep "1f 8b 08"
```

which seems to be like `0018864 8f 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 02 03 ec dd 79 7c 15`, therefore offset is *0018864+1*. So creating the vmlinux like so;

```
sudo dd if=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-77-generic bs=1 skip=18865 | zcat > /tmp/vmlinux-5.4.0-77
```

and extract dump into a folder

```
sudo apport-unpack /var/crash/_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_io.elementary.cerbere.1000.crash /tmp/crash/
```

produces below.

```
 $ ls -la /tmp/crash/
 total 26016
 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Jul  4 16:01 .
 drwxrwxrwt 16 root root     4096 Jul  4 16:08 ..
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root        5 Jul  4 16:01 Architecture
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 26558464 Jul  4 16:01 CoreDump
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root        8 Jul  4 16:01 CurrentDesktop
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root       24 Jul  4 16:01 Date
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root       19 Jul  4 16:01 DistroRelease
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root       47 Jul  4 16:01 ExecutablePath
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root       10 Jul  4 16:01 ExecutableTimestamp
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root        2 Jul  4 16:01 _LogindSession
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root        5 Jul  4 16:01 ProblemType
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root       47 Jul  4 16:01 ProcCmdline
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root       11 Jul  4 16:01 ProcCwd
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root       89 Jul  4 16:01 ProcEnviron
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root    10978 Jul  4 16:01 ProcMaps
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     1370 Jul  4 16:01 ProcStatus
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root        1 Jul  4 16:01 Signal
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root       29 Jul  4 16:01 Uname
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root       45 Jul  4 16:01 UserGroups
```

Still, I can't see the crash.

```
sudo crash /tmp/vmlinux-5.4.0-77 /boot/System.map-5.4.0-77-generic /tmp/crash/CoreDump

crash: /tmp/vmlinux-5.4.0-77: no debugging data available
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/796808/1198552
Created an `intel.conf` file as explained in that answer which solved my problem.